# how do I make a php footer dynamic copyright starting this year?

Tags: php, dynamic, footer, copyright-display

Here's my copyright as of right now:

`<i>Example.com</i> &copy; 2013 - <?php echo date('Y'); ?>`

this is okay next year because it will read:

> *Example.com* © 2013 - 2014

but this year it says: `© 2013-2013`

**How can I make it `© 2013` and auto switch to `© 2013-2014` next year, without having to come back and change it by hand?**

Comment: Use an if statement to check the year. if it's 2013, don't display the dash and second year. It's that simple.

Comment: Keep in mind that copyright notices do not have much of a legal meaning. Even if you automatically update your notice, the date of publication for your content would still be the date that you actually posted the content online.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should be

```
<i>Example.com</i> &copy; 2013 <?php (date('Y') !== "2013") echo "- " . date('Y')); ?>
```

Comment: so to test if its working I change it to 2012?:

`<?php (date('Y') == "2012" ? $year = "" : $year = "- ".date('Y')); echo $year; ?>`

Answer (score 3):

```
$startYear = 2013; 
$currentYear = date('Y');
echo $startYear;
if ($startYear != $currentYear) {
    echo '-' . $currentYear;
}
```

That handles the years part of the Copyright message, just enter the other formatting around the output as you require.

(I've aimed for the longer but more readable approach, take your pick)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the php code to get dynamic year as well as the domain of your hosting server

```
<?php echo "&copy; ". date(Y)." ".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ;?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<i>Example.com</i> &copy; 2013 <?=(date('Y')>2013?' - '.date('Y'):'')?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php function auto_copyright($year = 'auto'){ ?>
   <?php if(intval($year) == 'auto'){ $year = date('Y'); } ?>
   <?php if(intval($year) == date('Y')){ echo intval($year); } ?>
   <?php if(intval($year) < date('Y')){ echo intval($year) . ' - ' . date('Y'); } ?>
   <?php if(intval($year) > date('Y')){ echo date('Y'); } ?>
<?php } ?>
//where you want to use just paste it:
<?php auto_copyright('2010'); ?>//2010-2015
<?php auto_copyright(); ?>//current year i.e:2015
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<i>Example.com</i> &copy; <?php echo (date('Y')==2018)?(date('Y')):'2018 - '.date('Y'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<i>Example.com</i> &copy; <?php if (date('Y') != '2013') { echo '2013 - ' } echo date('Y'); ?>
```

Comment: could you append your answer with some commentary so that we could better understand your code?

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.